# How to get more than 100 rows from REST API through curl call

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using top=500 to display the items from SharePoint using below curl command, but still am getting only 100 rows in the out file:

```
curl -D ~/header_test.txt --ntlm --request GET --netrc "http://spappfarm.intratest.in/iapps/test_uat/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('test%20Class%20list%20FI')/items?$top=500" -o ~/out_test.txt
```

Can you please suggest how to get more than 100 rows from REST API through curl call?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the post under SharePoint Online, but your SharePoint URL seems to indicate an on-prem instance, so it is difficult to guess which version of SharePoint you're using.

In general, you should use `$top` with `$skip` together to make multiple calls until you get all the items you need rather than increasing the payload response size as most APIs will be designed to actively throttle and/or deny requests that can negatively impact the service.

Luckily, you don't have to keep track of what page you're on: most REST calls that support pagination will return a node with the URL for the next set of results. It is usually called `next` under the `links` node, but yours may be different based on your SharePoint version.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks Hugo , Yes there is another URL in the rel="next" which refers to next set of items in the out file  . we are using sharepoint 2013 vesion and we are going to get upgraded version SPSE.  does the $top=500 works (means whether it retrieve morethan 100 items to the outfile  ) in  SPSE version ? As we need to build solution which works for both versions of sharepoint